# Angular, Fill Dropdown with aggregation result

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, aggregation

I want to fill a dropdown list with my aggregation results that I get from elasticsearch.

my response all in all looks good

```
aggregations:{
        status:{
         buckets:{[
                 0:{key: "OPEN", doc_count: 57},
                 1:{key: "CLOSED", doc_count: 22}
                  ]}
                }
              }
```

Now i want to put the "key" in my dropdown variable.
it should look like this

```
$scope.Options = ['','OPEN','CLOSED'];
```

i tried

```
$scope.Options = response.aggregations.status.buckets;
```

that only gives me

`[{key: "OPEN", doc_count: 57}, {key: "CLOSED", doc_count: 22}]`

I don't know how to continue at this point.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.Options = [''].concat(response.aggregations.status.buckets.map(b => b.key))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $scope.Options = response.aggregations.status.buckets.map(function(item){ return item.key});
```